# Create splitting criterion for sklearn trees

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I need other splitting criteria for a Desicion tree than the provided 'gini' and 'entropy. I want to use the wonderful sklearn package as base though. Is there a way to go around the C-implementation of the tree building process? As in implementing the criterion in Python and let the TreeBuilder work with it?

Comment: It is Cython, not C, and even if it was possible, it would be too slow to be practical.

Comment: I'm such a dummy. of course it's cython. I'll code the split criterion in the .pyx file then. thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

As Andreas said above, splitting criteria are coded in cython.